# Which is the fastest way to loop? [for curiosity]

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to increase a variable from 0 to 1000000 in a fastest way. In this case i need to increase the variable value and measure the time to run all of this loops. Should i use a `while` loop, or a `setInterval()` with `0` of time interval is fastest?

```
var i = 0;
while(i <= 1000000){
  i++;
}

//VS

var i = 0;
setInterval(function(){
  if(i <= 1000000){
    i++
  }
},0)

//OTHER OPTIONS
//...
```

And how to measure that?

UPDATE

I think I expressed myself wrong, I want to actually reach 1 million by adding one by one to the variable. And thats my issue in measuring that, wich is the best way?

Comment: The fastest way is to add `1000000` to to it.

Comment: Why?  Is this some sort of bottleneck?  And I think your second method will crash the browser.

Comment: @Teepeemm It will not crash the browser - there's a 4ms delay added to `setTimeout` and `setInterval`, which will make it considerably slower than the first method. The first method will make the browser hang until it's done.

Comment: its a performance matter that i'm trying to understand better

Comment: https://jsperf.com

Comment: I'm not recommending the `setInterval` approach, but if you use it, make sure you clear the interval once you're done.  The current code will run the interval forever.

Comment: There few JSPerfs already setup for that: https://jsperf.com/fastest-array-loops-in-javascript/24 and https://jsperf.com/loops/33 are good examples.

Comment: @Teemu There's at least a 4ms delay with setTimeout. You can't be sure exactly when the callback will be run. The delay argument should be treated like a minimum time to wait, not an exact or maximum time.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes, I know that, maybe OP didn't. Anyway, jsperf is a good tool for OP to create their own tests, that's why the link. In modern browsers there is also [Performance API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance), and modern Dev Tools provide a set of profiling methods, [ex.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Timers)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Performing tests i discover that the `for` loop is the better option for this situation:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i){

      // Each iteration of the loop will make i
      // have a different value inside the loop

 }
```

And for measure the time i'm using `console.time()` and `console.timeEnd()`

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question correctly, you want to time the fastest way to preform some kind of loop.

There are a number of looping constructions in JavaScript that include:

- `for`
- `while`
- `do... while`
- recursion
- `setTimeout/setInterval`
- `for...in`
- `for...of`
- generators

Of these, the basic `for` loop is generally the fastest as it has the *least* overhead of any of the others.

`setTimeout` and `setInterval` will be among the slower because the `0` delay is not honored. Browsers do set up some internal minimum delay.

I've never used it, but I believe there is `postMessage` that can be used without delay.

Comment: You forgot jQuery :P

Comment: I couldn't think of a jquery-specific looping technique.  I *tried*.

Comment: jQuery will never be faster than standard JavaScript, since it's just a wrapper API back to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that neither of those would be the fastest way, but you must understand that there will be differences between browsers as implementations vary.

`setInterval` will definitely be the slowest because JavaScript runs in a single-threaded environment. Even with a delay of 0, all you are doing is queuing up the callback function for a time when the engine is idle, which won't be until your loop is done.

The fastest way is most likely going to be a standard for loop:

```
 var startTime = new Date();
 for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i){

      // Each iteration of the loop will make i
      // have a different value inside the loop

 }
 var diff = Math.abs(new Date() - startTime);

 console.log(diff);
```

This jsPerf compares `for` to `while` and for wins.  http://jsperf.com/looptoamillion/2

Answer (score 0):

To measure the time, you'll need to use JavaScript's [date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

```
var startTime = Date.now(); // Unix time in ms.
// ... Run the Loop here ...
var endTime = Date.now();
var diff = endTime - startTime;
```

The setInterval is like a sleep timer. The only thing that it's good for with 0ms is for pushing a process into the background. It turns a synchronous blocking process into an asynchronous one. The rest of the code below that setInterval block can then resume execution & the code in the setInterval block will begin to execute in the background. It's a pretty nifty trick, which I've used a lot of times... but it doesn't speed up your loops at all.